# How to enable Spartacus SSR on SAP Commerce Cloud in the Public

Tags: server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

We've tasted Spartacus SSR recently. It works on-prem according to the Spartacus documentation but when it's deployed on SAP Commerce Cloud in the Public it continues using client-side rendering.

Is there any special configuration on how to tell Cloud deployment to use SSR or it should guess it automatically?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `"enableSSR": true` option that you need to set in your *manifest.json* - see https://help.sap.com/viewer/1be46286b36a4aa48205be5a96240672/SHIP/en-US/cd5b94c25a68456ba5840f942f33f68b.html